# Android socket communication error(Clicking button, get out by force)

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, communication

I'm trying to make my application can communicate by socket(TCP).
My java code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static EditText msg;
private static EditText ip;
private static EditText port;
private static Button configure;
private String html = "";

private BufferedReader networkReader;
private BufferedWriter networkWriter;

//The code under need to run, button clicked
private String sendMsg = "";
private String sendIp = "";
private int sendPort;
private Handler mHandler;
private Socket socket;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    mHandler = new Handler();

    MainThread thread = new MainThread();
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();

    ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip);
    port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);
    msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg);

}


public void configure(View v) {
    sendMsg = msg.getText().toString();
    sendIp = ip.getText().toString();
    sendPort = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());

    try {
        setSocket(sendIp, sendPort);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (msg.getText().toString() != null || !msg.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(networkWriter, true);
        String return_msg = sendMsg;
        out.println(return_msg);
    }
}

/**
private Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {

    //private Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            String line;
            Log.w("Chatting is running", "chatting is running");
            line = networkReader.readLine();
            html = line;
            mHandler.post(showUpdate);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
};

private Runnable showUpdate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "received: " + html, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
 **/

public void setSocket(String sendIp, int sendPort) throws IOException {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(sendIp, sendPort);
        networkWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        //networkReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class MainThread extends Thread{
    public void run() {
        try{
            setSocket(sendIp,sendPort);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.naver.naverspeech.client.Main3Activity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Configure"
    android:id="@+id/sender"
    android:onClick="configure"
    tools:ignore="OnClick" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="port"
    android:id="@+id/port"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="IP address"
    android:id="@+id/ip"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/msg"
    android:hint="msg"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sender"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint = "input"
    android:id = "@+id/reader" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What should I do? I can't see any errors in log. But, when I click the button, application terminate by force.(Even, I fill up the port, ip and msg.)
(Suppose there's no error in XML code.)

log:
11-26 07:17:49.498 2866-2866/? D/ucsBai_ConnectionManager: mPackageReceiver Action android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
11-26 07:17:53.348 30670-30670/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 10084
11-26 07:17:53.348 30670-30670/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
11-26 07:17:53.358 30670-30670/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                         adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.ext.ui
11-26 07:18:00.578 31282-31282/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9080
11-26 07:18:00.578 31282-31282/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE

Umm... I changed my java code(configure(button) part) as

```
    public void configure(View v) {
    sendMsg = msg.getText().toString();
    sendIp = ip.getText().toString();
    sendPort = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());

    try {
        setSocket(sendIp, sendPort);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I added NetworkOnMainThreadException.
However, I can see 
error log:

12-03 02:12:56.100 25268-25268/com.naver.naverspeech.client E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.naver.naverspeech.client, PID: 25268
                                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716)
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7329)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716) 
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926) 
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7329) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "."
                                                                                  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                                  at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
                                                                                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
                                                                                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                                  at com.naver.naverspeech.client.Main3Activity.configure(Main3Activity.java:62)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716) 
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926) 
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7329) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: You posted the wrong part of the logcat. You should post the part with the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: public void configure(View v) {
        sendMsg = msg.getText().toString();
        sendIp = ip.getText().toString();
        sendPort = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());

        try {
            setSocket(sendIp, sendPort);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

right? but, I cannot see any problems. Should I make the program out the error from other sides?

Comment: If you have code to show us then put that nicely in your post in a code block. We do not like to read code from a comment. Do you?

Comment: Sorry. I rewrited my post.

Comment: Read your logcat. `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "." at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(`. There it is. Didnt you see that? `at com.naver.naverspeech.client.Main3Activity.configure(Main3Activity.java:62) at ` What is on line 62?

Comment: sendPort = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());
is line 62. This is for converting string data to int data.

Comment: Well then you now know what goes wrong! Isnt it? Strange you do not comment.

Comment: Do you mean I made a mistake when I convert data?(string to int)
Then, What should I do when converting data in java?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());`. I cannot see what the user typed in in that EditText port. Do you? Please tell what he typed in getting that error. Look at the error message as that tells you also what the user typed.